# Django QuerySet values() include ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-queryset

Django **2.2** provides a method [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values) on QuerySet to convert queryset to dictionary

I'm using the same in my application as

```
new_plan_quota = PlanQuota.objects.filter(
    **filter_query
).select_related('quota')

new_plan_quota_values = list(new_plan_quota.values())
```

Which generates a json string containing all fields of **PlanQuota** model.

The model is like

```
class PlanQuota(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    quota = models.ForeignKey(Quota)
```

How can I add fields of **Quota** model as well in the json?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194388/discussion-on-question-by-anuj-tbe-django-queryset-values-include-foreignkey-f).

Answer (score 5):

From the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

somthing like this:

```
new_plan_quota_values = list(new_plan_quota.values('name', 'quota__field1', 'quota__field2', ...))
```

you will need to explicit add the "name" from PLAN

BTW if you are 'listing'
the values outcome. consider using values_list filter

look here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: This way I will have to pass all fields manually. There are many fields in both models. (Truncated fields in the question, just for representation).

Comment: and do you wit to get all fields from quota model as well?

Comment: yes, I want all the fields from both models. If possible few fields can be excluded, like `id`, `created`.

Comment: sorry - but if so u need to build a serializer. or write them explicitly.

Comment: OR you can get all fields names from model._meta get_fields  docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model

Answer (score 0):

You can add desired fields owned by current model and related fields which owned by related model using `__` as string parameters in values.

Also you can set an alias for related fields using `F` like below.

```
from django.db.models.expressions import F
new_plan_quota_values = list(new_plan_quota.values('name', field_alias=F('quota__field')))
```

Comment: you do not need the expression import

Comment: It can be needed, suppose `quota` has another `name` and you want to use it as another key in the result dictionary.